# Elasticsearch - Why is it recommended to use 50% of available memory for the heap?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that ES recommends 50% of available memory for the heap, but something about that is confusing me: On a 2GB system, that would give 1GB for ES and 1GB for the OS.

Why on a 8GB system, do we need then to reserve 4GB for the OS rather than 1GB as on the smaller system?

P.S. I was debating whether this question belongs on StackOverflow or ServerFault. If this is the wrong place to post it, just mention it in the comments and I will move it.

Answer (score 4):

So first off keep in mind that the 50% of available memory is a good rule of thumb for starting things out, not carved in stone. It's assumed that as you gain experience with your specific environment, document volume, usage patterns, etc. that you can and will change this.

Everything not assigned to the JVM heap with be available to the OS, for both running processes and for caching the file system (which is important for ES performance). So if you set the heap too high (which some have done previously) you can end up starving the OS of memory, which can leave little for file system caching and in extreme cases can cause memory exhaustion, which under Linux can cause the OOM killer to be invoked.

It's generally assumed that as you increase server size you are increasing both your heap requirements AND your process running and file system cache requirements, so the rule of thumb stays constant at 50%. Nothing magic about it, just a ratio that people have found to be a good first starting point. Generally though if you need a larger server due to memory constraints you need both more heap AND OS memory so just keeping it at 50% to start makes good sense.

In actual production usage what you want to do is start at 50% and then measure heap usage, memory usage by the elasticsearch process and whether or not the OOM killer ever gets invoked. For many users, particularly on larger instances, the 50% heap allocation can be overkill. It all depends on your usage. Fortunately ES has pretty good stats info on heap usage right out of the box (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html).

For what it's worth on our production systems we try to keep our ES using about 75% of allocated heap which we default to 50% of memory. Anything above that and we get concern that a surge in indexing/big queries/etc could blow the heap - much below that and we're concerned that we're wasting memory in the heap that could be used for file system caching.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, most of elasticsearch's JVM heap usage is due to query filters and field data (facets/aggregations/sorting) and there weren't lots of safeguards in place to prevent OOM(this has changed).

In order to actually perform searches elasticsearch uses mmap'ed files and completely bypasses the JVM heap and hands off management of this to the OS disk cache, which does an amazing job of using every teeny bit of memory available to the OS and if you starve this your performance will suffer.

With recent updates, field data can now be stored directly to disk via doc_values. This tradeoffs the amount of data you can facet/aggregate/sort on with the speed as doc_values end up being a little slower than a pure in memory solution, YMMV.

My general recommendation post 1.x elasticsearch is to allocate 2-4GB to the JVM and ensure that you plan ahead and use doc_values on any high cardinality fields you plan to aggregate with.

So, the 50% number really is no longer valid, especially if your server is more than 64GB, as you really don't want to a heap that can't use CompressedOops (https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/35gb-heap-less-32gb-java-jvm-memory-oddities/).

Here is some great reading why you should love the disk cache:
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#persistence