# Elasticsearch: Aggregate results of query

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an elasticsearch index containing products, which I can query for different search terms. Every product contains a field `shop_id` to reference the shop it belongs to. Now I try to display a list of all shops holding products for my query. (To filter by shops)
As far as I read on similar questions, I have to use an aggregation. Finally I built this query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/searchindex/_search?search_type=count&pretty=true' -d '{
  "query" : {
      "match" : {
          "_all" : "playstation"
      }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "shops_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "shop_id"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This should search for `playstation` and aggregate the results based on `shop_id`. Sadly it only returns

> Data too large, data would be larger than limit of [8534150348]
>   bytes].

I also tried it with queries returning only 2 results.
The index contains more than 90,000,000 products.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest thats a job for a filter aggregation.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

Note: I don't know your product mapping in your index, so if that filter below doesn't work, try another filter from http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filters.html

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "in_stock_playstation" : {
            "filter" : { "term" : { "change_me_to_field_for_product" : "playstation" } } },
            "aggs" : {
                "shop_count" : { "terms" : { "field" : "shop_id" } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This results in a memory-error as well. I have a suspicion that elasticsearch tries to perform the aggregation before applying the filter. Even for queries returning only 2 results it fails.

Comment: Actually, filter aggregations filter, then aggregate (note the nesting of "aggs"). Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367420/elasticsearch-why-is-it-recommended-to-use-50-of-available-memory-for-the-hea